# Open Graph Facebook Cache

Tags: facebook, debugging, facebook-opengraph

Im trying not to get crazy but can please somebody answer this situation. I made a debug of my home page www.worldstoprestaurants.com and this is how it looks:

http://www.worldstoprestaurants.com/

```
<meta property="og:title" content="World&#039;s Top Restaurants - The Best Restaurants of the World" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.worldstoprestaurants.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://worldstoprestaurants.com/donnacarmela/2.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="World&#039;s Top Restaurants" />
<meta property="og:description" content="World&#039;s Top Restaurants is an online exclusive guide of restaurants around the world. Search for the best rest&#xf3; in the main cities of the world." />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="100002573447040" />
```

Everything looks ok and even if I share the webpage the result is what i have spected. Now if I directly copy the URL from the browser (http://www.worldstoprestaurants.com/) and I paste in Facebook it shows a totally diferent information. I think it shows a preview canonical URL but I have updated the webpage and debug. Does anyone knows what happen?

Best Regards,

Damian.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook OG debugger comes in handy here. Check out https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ and type in your URL and click "Fetch new scrape information" to refresh Facebook's cache.

Comment: Still having the same problem. The share function is ok. But if I directly paste the URL www.worldstoprestaurants.com on Facebook dialog box it shows a totally diferent info. I have already debugged like 10 times. Even is more wierd, if I directly paste the URL it shows one information.. before pushing the send buttton. After publishing the info changes again, and the name and information is ok, but the picture shown is wrong. Please try to put the URL yourself and see.